# Why are outside parries not used in rapier fencing?

Tags: fencing, historic-european, rapier

In sport fencing, two of the most common parries are parry four, a middle line parry to the inside, and parry six, a middle line parry to the outside. Last night, I went to a rapier class and the only parry that was taught before we also learned to use the dagger was a parry four analog. During drills, I also reflexively used parry six, and was told not to do that. What is the reasoning behind not using an outside parry?

Comment: Is this SCA-style light fencing? Another HEMA style?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that you'd have to ask the people at the rapier class you attended, because [not all HEMA practioners outlaw a *Sixte*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HanCU8rFdiM). It is possible that they don't actually have anything against a *Sixte*, but you were practicing a *Quarte*, so they were simply chiding you to follow the drill.

Comment: When I'm in a teaching or senior role I often say "that is an effective/useful/whatever technique or move, but NOT what we are studying now". Or "yeah, that works but it's not what we are practicing".